# How many times can I apply the windscreen washing fluid until it's empty?

Tags: windshield

How many times, in general, can I apply the windscreen washing fluid until it's empty? If the car has applications to both the front windscreen & back window, how does it count? Are those two separate containers or one container with two pipes?

If the answer varies greatly between models, my car is a Nissan Note.

Comment: Of course it depends on container size, which windows you spray and how long you spray each time. NOFI but was that really too hard to think of yourself?

Comment: @MadMarky I thought there may be like a standard container size or nozzle application that is used on most cars.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on:

1) how long you spray the washer fluid for...
And

2) some cars have separate bottles but most newer ones have only one : less for the owner to think about

3) some cars also have headlamp washers which also use that supply, usually only when the headlights are on though,

So, the answer is it depends...

Comment: For (1) is there a time limit? Like *it takes 60 seconds to empty the bottle*, then I can divide that by the duration of each application to get the answer.

Comment: Also, my 2016 RAV4 uses the headlamp washer only for the first, sixth, eleventh, sixteenth, and so on times the windscreen washer is operated. So, on a long drive, only one fifth of the windscreen washer applications results in a headlamp wash.

Comment: @juhist there are probably as many plans as manufacturers...

Comment: @kevin well, I have on one car in the past had to run the pump to empty out the reservoir and it did not stop... however, some cars may put a limit...